# YAML CI is flattening file structure

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm hosting my repo in GitHub and using Azure DevOps for the CI/CD pipelines. I've done this before using the GUI CI/CD screens with no problem.

The first thing that I've noticed is that the build process using YAML seems to flatten the file structure. I'm also seeing some XML and TXT files instead of the actual JSON files in the drop folder.

So, in the drop folder instead of seeing drop/AzureResourceGroup/azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json I see drop/TestYAML.Parameters.xml

Build and Publish tasks:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs: 
  - job: Build

    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'

    variables: 
      solution: '**\*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
      

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'      
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs: 
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:SourceLinkCreate=true'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs: 
        pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
        artifactName: 'drop' 
        publishLocation: 'container' # Options: container, filePath
        #targetPath: # Required when publishLocation == FilePath
        #parallel: false # Optional
        #parallelCount: # Optional
        #fileCopyOptions: #Optional
```

**Edited to show package contents**.

After I download and unzip the file, this is what I see. The files from two different projects are shoved under the same folder:
[image]

Files immediately available in the artifact:
[image]

VS Build Log:

Comment: Obviously this is not a correct behavior. But you do not share some useful info, we could not give any useful info. According to your YAML, the drop folder should include the files `TheProjectName.zip`, `TheProjectName.SetParameters.xml` and so on. Is this file `azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json` included in your generated package? Would you share your VSbuild log and file directory structure in your repo about the file `azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json`?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I added the screen shots to show the drop and package contents. The VSBuild Log was too long to paste in the body, and I didn't see a way to attach a separate log file.

Comment: I have gave a answer for this issue, please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I had was that the azuredeploy JSON files weren't in the drop folder after the build task to be used by the deployment task(s). I would up having to use the Copy Files task to be able to get the files there.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AzureResourceGroup'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: TestYAML\AzureResourceGroup
        Contents: '*.json'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AzureResourceGroup'
```

While this works, I don't understand why Microsoft breaks away from automatically including these files. I don't know if the difference is YAML or .NET Core vs .NET Framework, but the build pipelines I set up using the GUI on other projects that have azuredeploy JSON files include this step as part of the Build task.

Answer (score 0):

> YAML CI is flattening file structure

This is an expected behavior. MSBuild will create the following files in the package location when we publish a `ASP.NET Core` project as package:

[image: TestYAML.deploy.cmd TestYAML.deploy-readme.txt]

Because "`AlwaysCreate`" was specified, and "`AlwaysCreate`" is a part of Visual Studio build environment settings and is part of the `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets` XML file:

[image]

So, the file `TestYAML.Parameters.xml` **was expected as it was generated**, instead of replacing the file `AzureResourceGroup/azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json`.

Besides, if you have any file like `AzureResourceGroup/azuredeploy.parameters-dev.json` added to the project, you could check if add it. And if you want add this json file to the publish out, you could set the **Build Action** for that json file to `Content`, it will be included in the `.zip` file:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that's the difference. It treats .NET Framework and .NET Core differently. We have projects using Azure Databases, Function Apps, and Service Bus queues, all using ARM templates to set them up, but the main projects are still in .NET Framework for some reason.